# Destructor of typedef alias

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, destructor, typedef

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { ~A(); };
A::~A() {
    std::cout << "Destructor was called!" << std::endl;
}

typedef A AB;
int main() {
    AB x;
    x.AB::~AB(); // Why does this work?
    x.AB::~A();
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
Destructor was called!
Destructor was called!
Destructor was called!
```

I assume the first two lines belonging to user destructor calls, while the third line is due to the destructor being called when exiting the scope of `main` function.

From my understanding a typedef is an alias for a type. In this case `AB` is an alias for `A`.

Why does this apply for the name of the destructor too? A reference to the language specification is very much appreciated.

Edit: This was compiled using Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1) on macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.3.

Comment: That code is remarkably similar to an example in §3.4.3 in C++11.

Comment: Note that the destructor doesn't formally have a name (and neither do constructors).

Comment: @molbdnilo I wrote this example some time ago. When I remember correctly, it was inspired from an entry on cppreference, so I guess they in turn took the example from the language standard.

Comment: Btw, you invoke UB by destroying several times the same object.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Why does this apply for the name of the destructor too?

Because standard says:

> [class.dtor]
>
> In an explicit destructor call, the destructor is specified by a ~ followed by a type-name or decltype-specifier
>   that denotes the destructor’s class type. ...

A typedef alias is a type-name which denotes the same class as the type-name of the class itself.

The rule even has a clarifying example:

> ```
> struct B {
>   virtual ~B() { }
> };
> struct D : B {
>   ~D() { }
> };
>
> D D_object;
> typedef B B_alias;
> B* B_ptr = &D_object;
>
> void f() {
>   D_object.B::~B();             // calls B's destructor
>   B_ptr->~B();                  // calls D's destructor
>   B_ptr->~B_alias();            // calls D's destructor
>   B_ptr->B_alias::~B();         // calls B's destructor
>   B_ptr->B_alias::~B_alias();   // calls B's destructor
> }
> ```

---

Further specification about the name lookup, also with an example that applies to the question:

> [basic.lookup.qual]
>
> If a pseudo-destructor-name ([expr.pseudo]) contains a
>   nested-name-specifier, the type-names are looked up as types in the
>   scope designated by the nested-name-specifier. Similarly, in a
>   qualified-id of the form:
>
> nested-name-specifieropt class-name :: ~ class-name
>
> the second class-name is looked up in the same scope as the first.
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct C {
>   typedef int I;
> };
> typedef int I1, I2;
> extern int* p;
> extern int* q;
> p->C::I::~I();      // I is looked up in the scope of C
> q->I1::~I2();       // I2 is looked up in the scope of the postfix-expression
>
> struct A {
>   ~A();
> };
> typedef A AB;
> int main() {
>   AB* p;
>   p->AB::~AB();     // explicitly calls the destructor for A
> }
> ```
>
> — end example  ]

Comment: ... and the name is looked up in the global scope instead of the scope of `A` per [basic.lookup.qual]/6.

Answer (score 7):

Because when you write `~AB()` you are not naming or calling the destructor. You are writing `~` followed by <strike>the</strike> a name of the class, and the destructor call is automatically provisioned as a result of the specified semantics of writing those tokens next to each other.

Usually this is academic but here you see why it can matter.

Similarly, by writing `AB()` you are not "calling a constructor", even though this looks like a function call and many language newcomers interpret the code this way. (This can lead to fun and games when attempting to call a template constructor without argument deduction: without being able to name the constructor, there's no way to provide those arguments!)

In fact, neither the constructor nor the destructor technically even *have* a name!

These nuances make C++ fun, right?

Comment: (More "fun" answer to complement the thick standardese that was actually requested)

Comment: By that metric, C++ has order-of-magntiudes more fun-per-bit than any other popular computer language.

Comment: @Eljay And that's why we love it ^_^

Comment: I think this is not just more "fun" but also a very useful and informative answer.

Comment: @molbdnilo Well, I don't like to brag ;) (yes I do)