# Unable to manually call destructor of std::string

Tags: c++

I'm experimenting with unions and made this example class A with anonymous union member. Since the union contains a `std::string` and a `std::vector` I needed to define a destructor for the class. But, when I try to manually call `~string()` I get

```
union.cpp: In destructor 'A::~A()':
union.cpp:14:14: error: expected class-name before '(' token
    s_.~string();
```

I don't get this with the vector. If I remove the call to `s._~string();` it compiles fine. Is this a compiler bug? I'm using MinGW64.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class A
{
    public:
    explicit A(const std::string &s) : s_ {s}, is_string {true} {}
    explicit A(const std::vector<int> &v) : v_ {v}, is_string {false} {}

    ~A()
    {
        if (is_string)
            s_.~string();
        else
            v_.~vector();
    }

    private:
    union
    {
        std::string s_;
        std::vector<int> v_;
    };
    bool is_string;

};

int main()
{
    A a("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Using `std::delete_at(std::addressof(s_))` does work with `-std=c++17`. What's going on here?

Comment: The class is called `std::string`, not just `string`

Comment: @UnholySheep `std::string` doesn't seem to work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd0d78d2219c168a

Comment: adding `std::` namespace qualifier for either gives `main.cpp:13:20: error: expected class-name before '::' token`

Comment: Calling destructors manually is, in 99.9% of cases (or roughly thereabouts) a bug. Rare cases, involving `placement new` are the exception, but that's not what you are doing here. *Don't* manually call destructors. They will be called *for you* when objects go out of scope or containing objects are destroyed. Yes, you *can* call them manually, but you *should not*. If you think you need to, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Calling destructors manually is needed when implementing something similar to `std::variant`, which is exactly what OP is doing here. Though of course using `std::variant` itself would be better.

Comment: @interjay Ooh didn't know about `std::variant`. Is that the C++17 replacement of a union?

Comment: @DavidTran `std::variant` is more of a type-safe replacement for a "tagged union" (i.e. a union plus a field saying which member is active).

Comment: @interjay Do you suggest using a "tagged union" rather than what is being used here? What are the tradeoffs?

Comment: @DavidTran std::variant is C++17 but you can use boost::variant for the same purpose. Only the visitor interface is different.

Comment: What you used *is* a tagged union. It isn't type-safe because you might accidentally access an inactive member if you aren't careful. `std::variant` and `boost::variant` are safe because they throw an exception if you access the wrong member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

std::string is not a real type but a typedef.

```
using std::string = std::basic_string<char>;
```

So you need to call basic_string destructor.

```
~A()
{
    if (is_string)
        s_.~basic_string();
    else
        v_.~vector();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the standard specifically give examples of manually calling a destructor through a typedef?

Comment: @JohnGowers: Correct, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256851/destructor-of-typedef-alias.

Comment: in that case, why is this answer necessary? Doesn't this imply that `s_.~string()` should work, even though it does not? In fact, page 41 of Scott Meyers' "More Effective C++" also claims that `~string()` should work...????

Comment: this answer is actually wrong! It claims that you cannot call destructor through a typedef, but if I do `typedef std::string Foo` then `s_.~Foo()` works perfectly (I'm using macOS Apple clang version 13.1.6 with -std=c++98.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem, and the following worked for me:

```
typedef std::string string_alias;
sp->~string_alias();
```

It seems the C++ compiler is confused by the `~std::string` part of the statement.

Comment: The compiler has good reason to be confused. You're destructing a string, not an entire namespace. The `~` goes after the `std::`, so `std::~string`.

Comment: gcc 10.3.0 says: `error: scope ‘std’ before ‘~’ is not a class-name` to `sp->std::~string();`. How should I write it without the typedef?

Comment: this answer is actually more correct than the accepted one, though it's still not certain why the C++ compiler would be confused by the typedef inside std of string to basic_string<char>. I would really like to know the answer to that...